# how to load the dynamic data from server on uitableview

Tags: ios

i'm beginner to ios development, i need to load the dynamic data from server on the tableview if anybody knows the code please share it.

Thanks in advance,
Abe.

Answer (score 5):

Use Core data and [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), via delegate methods of tableview controller populate tableview from NSFetchedResultsController instance.. It reflects deleting, adding and any kind of updates on database automotically onto tableview.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the level of complexity of your model and on what kind of caching policy you need, there are different ways to connect a table view to a remote data source. There would be tons of things to say here, but the best for you, if you are a beginner, is to take a look to some examples around the Internet.

There are "few" open source project for network communication that offer good ways and good examples (source code included) to deal with server driven apps. I cite the two I prefer:

- [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) : there are example sources with this library and UITableViewController that may fit your need
- [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) : this will turn useful if you want to map and persist the server-returned data to local model. This may require some more learning time though.

But remind that you anyway need to know the basics of a [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the related protocols: [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). The documentation is ok, but you may even want to take a look to the [WWDC 2011 podcast](https://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.4092349126.04109539109.4144345631?i=1314817424) about table views.

Moreover, if you need data persistence as well, you should start looking into [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) and the [NSFetchedResultControllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), as illis and Bogdan said, but things will start getting a little bit trickier.

Answer (score 2):

Actually NSFetchedResultsController is a bit hard for understanding.

You should try to handle UITableView data by yourself. Take a look at [UITableViewDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Here are some steps for you to follow:

1) Create a class that will inherit UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource

```
@interface YourTableViewController: UITableViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
```

2) Create an Array that will hold your data

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *data;
```

3) Implement this methods:

```
    - (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
        DataObject *d=[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // selected data, now you can handle it        
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return data.count;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)mtableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        NSString *ident=@"CatalogCell";       
        UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ident];       
        if (cell==nil) {           
            cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:ident] autorelease];          
        }
        DataObject *d=[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.textLabel setText:d.someField];      
    }
```

4) Select some method ( [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) , ASIHTTPRequest (sorry, only 2 hyperlinks allowed for me) or other) to get data from server

```
-(void) parseData:(NSString *) d {
    NSArray * parsedData=[self someMethodToParseData:d];
    [data setArray:parsedData];
    [tableView reloadData];    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASIHTTPRequest library to get data from your server. You can find some information about it on http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

You can use http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-use-tableview-in-iphone/ this link to more information about the tableview.

In link's tutorial, you must request your data in viewDidload method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    // Request your data on this line.
    /*NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]     initWithObjects:@"Sleepy",@"Sneezy",@"Bashful",@"Happy",@"Doc",
                        @"Grmpy",@"Dopey",@"Thorin",@"Dorin",@"Nori",
                        @"Ori",@"Balin",@"Dwalin",@"Fili",@"Kili",@"Oin",                                                
                        @"Gloin",@"Bifur",@"Bofur",@"Bombur",nil ];*/

     self.listData = array;
     [array release];
     [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

All of these are simply usage. You must experience with more example to use more complex situation. i will add more code for a tutorial to fetch data from server and show on tableview.